# Trouble setting the height of ionic button-bar

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am creating a mobile app with ionic framework. I want to adjust the button bar to a little bit smaller. I tried the following code and nothing seems to be happening.[image: Please refer to this image.]

```
    <div class="button-bar" style="height:1%;">
        <button class="button button-outline button-full button-energized"><b>Connection</b></button>       
        <button class="button button-outline button-full button-energized"><b>
        My Music</b></button>    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I can't actually utilize ionic classes in jsfiddle. Try the following:

```
    <div class="button-bar" style="height:50px;">
        <button class="button button-outline button-full button-energized">  <b>Connection</b></button>       
        <button class="button button-outline button-full button-energized"><b>
        My Music</b></button>    
    </div>
```

Try to actually use a pixel value instead of a %. The percentage isn't going to give you the result you want in this particular instance. Percentage will only work if the parent container has a set height.

Also, You can try targetting the individual buttons like this:

```
       <div class="button-bar"">
            <button class="button button-outline button-full button-energized" style="height:50px;>  <b>Connection</b></button>       
            <button class="button button-outline button-full button-energized" style="height:50px;><b>
            My Music</b></button>    
        </div>
```

I personally would recommend creating a separate style sheet to accomplish this and just target the button-bar or the button directly like this:

CSS:

```
.button {
  height: 50px;
}
```

or

```
.button-bar {
  height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some min-height adding on button from ionic.css. overide it using .button-bar .button {min-height: some px}

Comment: You are so brilliant.